# Trying to persist an object in mysql database

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have created a mySQL database with some tables, the relevant ones for my problem are Players and Season.

Table season contain:

```
Season_id (int),seasonNumber(int),total(int), week(int), value(int), totalsell(int)
```

I have my Java code, where i did create my entities and using anotations i identified the entities as well as my primary key for each entitie.

Here are the atributes of my Season POJO class:

```
private int id;
private LinkedList<Player> keepers;
private LinkedList<Player> defs;
private LinkedList<Player> inners;
private LinkedList<Player> wings;
private LinkedList<Player> innersTreino;
private LinkedList<Player> strikers;
private LinkedList<Player> strikersTreino;
private int seasonNumber;
private LinkedList<Player> vendas;
private LinkedList<Player> sold;
private int total;
private int week;
private int value; 
private int totalsell;
```

After that i created my entitymanagerFactory and my entity manager, and try to test if i can fill my database:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("htTeamPU");
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

  em.getTransaction().begin();
  Season test = new Season();
  test.setSeasonNumber(43);
  test.setTotal(5);
  test.setWeek(100);
  test.setValue(200);
  test.setTotalsell(10);

  em.persist(test);
  em.getTransaction().commit();
  em.close();
  emf.close();
```

When i run my program i have an exception:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'DEFS' in 'field list'
```

The problem seems to be that my object as 9 linkedLists of Players, and i don't have them represented on my **season** table. I don't really know how to represent the linked lists on my season table to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should make many-to-many relationship with Player and Seoson tables.

For one of your lists;

At the owning side (Seoson)

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "seoson_keepers", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Seoson_id")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Player_id")})  
private List<Player> keepers;
```

At the inverse side (Player)

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, 
            mappedBy = "keepers")
private List<Seoson> seosons;
```

You can find more details about many-to-many relationships in jpa [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#eentity-mapping-association-collection-manytomany).

According to your design, you must repeat above code for all your lists.

Comment: Ty, for your time. Why many to many?  A player only have one season.. One season have many players.. So the relationship should be one to many  :-(

Comment: Yes , a player only have one seoson at current time but i thought he plays more seosons in his football life :) so you can hold current seoson variable also.

Comment: In my sw they will have only one season.  So I will use 1 to many..  So considering that what anotations should i make on my linked lists in order to not have an exception?

Comment: Then you can use OneToMany anotation in your Seoson entity and ManyToOne anotation in your Player entity.

Comment: But Regarding the linked lists i must do Something in order to not have an error?  And in my tables in the database?  Because what i have its a linked list of Player I dont Want to add a field on the table..

Comment: Could you explain me How the code will be for a one to many relation so that i dont have an error Because of my linked lists?

Comment: Look at here ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971010/persisting-linkedlist-in-hibernate

You can do like that ; private List keepers = new LinkedList();

Comment: Was asking what are the Right anotations?  I dont use hibernate

Comment: it is same with jpa. There is no special anotation for linked list.